# filtering two arrays with JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a list of checkboxes on a UI that user's can use to toggle and filter a set of data results. The checkboxes can be cumulative so I store them as a string array for now. My code looks something like this.

```
export interface IMyObjectFromAPI {
   status: {
      id: number,
      description: string,
      location: string,
      name: string,
      imageUrl: string
  }
}

var filteredByTerms: string[] = [];
var resultsFromAPI: IMyObjectFromAPI [] = [];
var filteredDataResults: IMyObjectFromAPI[] = [];
```

I save the return results from the api call into the `resultsFromAPI` array.

On the UI, I have a group of checkboxes based on countries that is populated with a loop through a countries array. On select of a checkbox, I fire off the following code. Again, the goal here is to add multiple things to the array of terms to filter by (so I want to filter by location + name).

```
filterDataResults(term: string) {
  var indexOfTerm = this.filteredByTerms.indexOf(term);
  // if the term is not in an array of terms to filter by, add it
  if (indexOfTerm === -1) {
   this.filteredByTerms.push(term);
   this.filteredDataResults = this.resultsFromAPI.filter(x => x.location === 
                              this.filteredByTerms.includes(term));
  }
   else {
     this.filteredByTerms.splice(indexOfTerm, 1);
     this.filteredDataResults = this.resultsFromAPI.filter(x => x.location === 
                                this.filteredByTerms.includes(term));
  }
}
```

I don't know if I'm explaining this correctly but I've attached a picture to help. A series of checkboxes on the left, a data set on the right, and the checkboxes can be cumulative (so in the image example, if I select ITContractor and Clinical Psychology, the filter function would look for something in the results returned from the API which statifies both conditions.

[image]

Comment: In your example, `filteredByTerms` is array of locations?

Comment: yes, but I want to make it so that it can be any property on the resultsfromAPI array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some HOFs and map of filters might help you organize your user determined logic/filtering.

```
const filters = {
  lastHourFilter: (result) => result.postedDate > Date.now() - ms('1 hour'),
  last24HoursFilter: (result) => result.postedDate > Date.now() - ms('24 hours'),
  ...
  itContractorFilter: generateSpecialismFilter('IT Contractor'),
  clinicalPsychologyFilter: generateSpecialismFilter('Clinical Psychology'),
  ...
  fullTimeFilter: generateJobTypeFilter('Full Time'),
  temporaryFilter: generateJobTypeFilter('Temporary')
}
```

Then you inspect the check boxes and determine which filters you should apply to the results. Something like:

```
function applyFilters(results) {
  Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
    if (checkboxes[key].checked) results = 
  results.filter(filters[key]);
  });
  return results;
}
```

Here checkboxes is a map of checkboxes in the DOM indexed by the same keys as your filters.

Comment: I like this but am curious about the implementation of this line: Here checkboxes is a map of checkboxes in the DOM indexed by the same keys as your filters.

Comment: Something like
```
checkboxes = { lastHourFilter: document.getElementById('lastHourFilterCheckbox'), ...
```